# How to execute a function with different arguments while having multiple ID's in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, function, flask

I have a table showing me two parameters. What I would like to do is change the value of each of these parameters when a button is clicked. So each parameter has its own button with its own specific Ids (made with jinja2). for the value to be changed, I have to take the name of the parameter as an argument in a function, please look at the below picture:

[my actual setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2wxf.png)

So I have my input box and my button to be clicked:

```
<td> <input type=number size=5 id="{{key}}"> </td>
<td> <button onClick="change('{{key}}')" name="{{key}}">change value</button> </td>
```

the hard part is that, the change has to be made by executing a python script, so my function is described as :

```
function change(key){
$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_change_value', {
    a: $('input[name="key"]').val(),
    b: $('button[name="key"]').val()}, function(data) { alert("Value was changed to " + data.result);});
```

}

For testing purpose I just made a python function that will return a only, to check if all went good, but unfortunately.

```
@app.route('/_change_value')
def change_value():
a = request.args.get('a', 0, type=int)
b = request.args.get('b', 0, type=int)
return jsonify(result=a)
```

a is returned as 0 always... I'm glad if someone can help me with this
I'm pretty sure the value key is not passed. Thanks a lot in advance

Edit: I made a mistake posting this question, id is present instead of name for the input, but still that did not resolve my problem...

Comment: you have no input with `name="key"` ... nor a button with `name="key"` (unless `{{key}}` becomes `key` but that would be silly to use `{{key}}` for a static value `key`)

Comment: @Diamondx What are value you want to capture? One is parameter, next is input textbox value, what else?

Comment: for my function to work, I just need to pass the name of the parameter which is {{key}}, but a need to be equal the input text box, and b need to equal the name of the parameter

Comment: @Diamondx If I'm not wrong then name of the parameter is the 1st column data. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solutio https://jsfiddle.net/1dvjqy11/

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var a = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="number"]').val();
  var b = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').first().html();
  console.log(a, b);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Parameter</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>GPS_Inject_to</td>
      <td>127</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" size=5 />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>
          Change Value
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>RPM2_SCALING</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" size=5 />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>
          Change Value
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've used `jQuery closest` to get the parent `tr` and used `jQuery find` method to find the child elements.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This worked, I had to tweak it a bit:

<script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
    $('button#calculate').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_change_value', {
        a: $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="number"]').val(),
        b: $(this).closest('tr').find('td').first().html()
      }, function(data) {
        alert(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>

Comment: @Diamondx That's awesome. Can you please accept the answer if you are satisfied.